# Display custom messages based on user role while logging in

Tags: customization, redirect

I have a site with two user roles Agent and Agency. When a non-logged in user clicks on a page link they will be redirected to login page. When they try to login, Agency users should be redirected to previous page and agent users should be shown a custom message that they need Agency login to view that page.
I am not able to achieve the last part of showing the message. Could you please help me with this?